# get a column data from a gridview

Tags: c#

i have generated the event of a button field  so that i get the index of the row  but i couldn't get the content of the column
could you help me please 
can i use select query  in which i pass the index of the row (I don't know how to write the condition  in the where clause)

```
Protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
    { 
            if (e.CommandName == "affichediplome") { 
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index]; 
            int ServerID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value); MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
          }
    }
```

Comment: Please add brief and related code and tell what problem you are having.

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "affichediplome")
            {    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);                   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];                                                   int ServerID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
                MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());}}

Comment: Please update your question with this, also tell if you need column value in the event or you need help to write query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Add a bound filed to store the information which you do not want to show to user but you have to use it at server side.

```
<asp:datagrid GridLines="None"  id="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Runat="server" BorderStyle="None">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sr. No."  ItemStyle-Width="5%">
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ModuleName" HeaderText="Module Name">
</asp:BoundColumn>
</asp:datagrid>
```

Then at the server side you can get this data as follows.

```
Private Sub dg_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgWebinarData.ItemDataBound
Dim str as string = string.empty
str = e.Item.Cells(1).Text
End sub
```

Note: e.Item.Cells(1) will give you ID if and only if when ID will be your first column of grid, else provide the column number.

Comment: houw could i specify the index of the row in this code ?

Comment: Index of the row means, you need to target a particular row from all the row that exist in data grid? If yes then you need to iterate in GridView based on some condition till you do not reach to desired row. Like this.. 
If StrComp(Trim(e.Item.Cells(1).Text), "NA", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
                    e.Item.Cells(x).Text = "Pass"
                End If

Comment: no I don't want to compare i want to get the content of each each column to use it after that

Comment: Then *e.Item.Cells(1).Text* will work fine for you in *dg_ItemDataBound*.
Note Cells(1) will return you data of first column of grid (visibility doesn't matter. If you have set visible=false for some column, even then that column will be in count). With each iteration you will reach next row and *e.Item.Cells(x).Text* will return you data.

Comment: i'm having this error what should i do                                                                                                              Error 35 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\ew\ew\WebFormconsult.aspx.cs

Comment: Okay which version are you using? and Do you have access to this grid control in your server side code?

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2013 the ultimate version  and  i'm using visual studio's server